# What is the component of this component in DevExpress?

Tags: .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, xaf

How is this happening here? Tab controller?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the [XtraTabbedMdiManager](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5488) is demonstrated at the screenshot with Office 2010 Black [skin](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2399) applied:

[image: XtraTabbedMdiManager]

PS. In new projects, I suggest you use the [DocumentManager's](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11359) [TabbedView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11355) as the advanced alternative.

Answer (score -2):

It is done in Devexpress XtraReport.